# vis.js How to move item in timeline to a desired date

Tags: vis.js

Is there anyway to in vis.js to move a list of items to a desired date on method onMove()?

I can't find any documentation for it. Would appreacite an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [this](http://visjs.org/examples/timeline/editing/editingItemsCallbacks.html) example.

When `onMove` is called, the function provides a callback, which allows you to change the affected item by altering its properties however you need to and then passing that changed item to the callback.  Otherwise, if you want to discard/prevent making any changes to that item, you pass null to the callback.

If you wish to change more items than that single item that was moved, utilize the `DataSet`.  Most of the examples use a `DataSet` for declaring items and initializing the timeline with those items. Use this `DataSet` reference when `onMove` is called.  Before passing the moved item to the callback, get the items from your `DataSet` that you want to change, alter their properties as needed, then pass these modified items back to your `DataSet` by calling the `DataSet.update()` method.